# pandas rows as column names - reshaping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have table in the following format:

```
  user_id   total_spent purchase_date   purchase_id aisle   department  item_cost
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          gn      1           25.7
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          aj      2           17
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          bs      2           31.7
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          jt      3           30
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          tj      3           8.1
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          ga      4           60.6
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          tw      4           35.9
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          aw      5           34.1
    33      279.3       1/29/18         26          te      5           36.2
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          je      1           93.5
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          tg      2           21.1
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          ds      2           23.2
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          jw      3           48.8
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          df      3           10.2
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          lj      4           56.2
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          oa      4           7
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          aw      5           32.4
    26      331.7       11/15/17        85          cm      5           39.3
```

And would like to convert it into each **department value as a column name** like **department_1, department_2** etc. Same as aisle and item cost: **dept_aisle_gn, dept_aisle_df** etc followed by corresponding cost as columns.

In other words, in the end, I would like to have **2 rows for 2 user_ids and the rest of the information will be shown in the columns rather than rows.**

Originally I pulled the data from redshift and I will manipulate it with python pandas. Unfortunately, pivot or crosstab is not working for redshift. I tried pandas pivot but seems not working for me.

Thank you.

Comment: please add the content of your csv file instead of the picture

Comment: I just added the content above. @EspoirMurhabazi Thank you!

Comment: You want a unique column for every single Item cost? If so, I suspect there is probably a better way to represent the data depending on your application.

Comment: I want a single column per user_id, showing each dept as columns and the rest as rows.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.pivot_table` supports this.

```
pd.pivot_table(df,
               index=['user_id', 'total_spent', 'purchase_date', 'purchase_id'],
               columns=['aisle', 'department'],
               values='item_cost',
               aggfunc=np.sum,
               fill_value=0)

# aisle                                          aj    aw    bs    cm    df  \
# department                                      2     5     2     5     3   
# user_id total_spent purchase_date purchase_id                               
# 26      331.7       11/15/17      85            0  32.4   0.0  39.3  10.2   
# 33      279.3       1/29/18       26           17  34.1  31.7   0.0   0.0   

# aisle                                            ds    ga    gn    je  jt  \
# department                                        2     4     1     1   3   
# user_id total_spent purchase_date purchase_id                               
# 26      331.7       11/15/17      85           23.2   0.0   0.0  93.5   0   
# 33      279.3       1/29/18       26            0.0  60.6  25.7   0.0  30   

# aisle                                            jw    lj oa    te    tg   tj  \
# department                                        3     4  4     5     2    3   
# user_id total_spent purchase_date purchase_id                                   
# 26      331.7       11/15/17      85           48.8  56.2  7   0.0  21.1  0.0   
# 33      279.3       1/29/18       26            0.0   0.0  0  36.2   0.0  8.1   

# aisle                                            tw  
# department                                        4  
# user_id total_spent purchase_date purchase_id        
# 26      331.7       11/15/17      85            0.0  
# 33      279.3       1/29/18       26           35.9
```

Comment: thank you for your response @jpp. but the aisle should be a row value not a column. any other suggestions regarding that?

Comment: pd.pivot_table(df,
               index=['user_id', 'total_spent', 'purchase_date', 'purchase_id', 'aisle'],
               columns=['department'],
               values='item_cost',
               aggfunc=np.sum,
               fill_value=0).reset_index()